# js Division of string to array

Tags: javascript

I want to divide a JavaScript string of characters into an Array, so that this:

```
"emad566"
```

becomes this:

```
["e","m","a","d","5","6","6"]
```

also I want to reverse it to become this:

```
["6","6","5","d","a","m","e"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

```
var arr =  mystring.split("").reverse();
```

Comment: There are no commas in the original string

Comment: @rich.okelly: Good point. Fixed. I was seeing the array output as the string. I think I'll format the question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "emad566"
arr = str.split('').reverse()
```

Then arr is `["6", "6", "5", "d", "a", "m", "e"]`